# How to get gh api command to ignore errors so it does not drop out of loops?

Tags: github-api, github-cli

I am trying to run in a loop some gh api GET commands (Github cli), but it stops once it hits any error (e.g., the url not found or whatever it was filtered on and looking for was not found).  I would rather capture the stderr and do something based on the error and continue with the loop.

```
for teamname in ${teamslist[*]}; do
 
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token token" -X GET https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/teams/$teamname/external-groups

{
  "message": "This team cannot be externally managed since it has explicit members.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/teams#list-external-idp-group-team-connection"
}

stderr is 1 in this case and it drops out of the loop.  fyi, this is running in a Github Action.  I was not sure if gh had an enviroment variable to ignore errors, or if there was some other way to ignore the stderr.
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of looking at things and trying various things (e.g., use trap, redirect with things like 2>/dev/null, various jq filter options, a github variable to ask it to ignore error, I found one example that did something really simple and sweet:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token token" -X GET https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/teams/$teamname/external-groups || echo "No AD group associated with this team"
```

It is the simple use of the || (or) and any command that succeeds that got around my issue.  In essence, the last exit code would be for the echo command if the first command has a non-zero exit code that allows the Github Action workflow to work.